# How do I run a macro on Microsoft Word on the web?

Tags: microsoft-word

I want to run a macro on MS Word but I do not have the desktop app. I can run MS Word on the web and I was wondering where the feature was for it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

At this point, macros do not work in Office Online.

Per Microsoft:

> Word Macro-Enabled Document (.docm) or Word Macro-Enabled Template
> (.dotm) The document can be opened, but macros do not run.

and

> Macros
>
> You can view, edit, print, and share documents that contain macros,
> but to run the macros click **Open in Word**.

Reference:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/differences-between-using-a-document-in-the-browser-and-in-word-3e863ce3-e82c-4211-8f97-5b33c36c55f8

Comment: how do i open a .docm doc?

Comment: @Haversine - in offline MS Word installed on your local machine.

Comment: i dont have the desktop app

Comment: Then you cannot open a docm file.

Comment: I agree with essjae, you need the desktop apps to create, run, or edit macros. But you can open and edit a document that contains macros on Word for web.